# Google Ads Conversion tracking for WEB

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-ads-script, conversion-tracking

I am having a hard time to find a documentation for web conversion tracking for Google Ads.

I would like to understand more about the HTTP POST request that is sent to Google.
I can see there is a good documentation for mobile apps:
https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/api/request-response-specs?hl=en#conversion_tracking_request

Is there similar documentation for web? I would like to understand more how i could send conversions to Google creating manually my HTTP request.

I am aware of the Offline conversions API (https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/samples/upload-offline-conversion), but it doesn't support the new parameters as wbraid

Comment: I don't think there's any specific docs on web conversions other than `gtag` https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6095821?hl=en